# Display total cart shipping volume value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, volume

I use woocommerce for wholesale customers who order containers of furniture - normally 40 foot containers with a volume of 68 cubic meters.

Is there a way I can show somewhere on the website - maybe in the header area a box with showing the total m3 of products in their basket? I need to show the client when they reach 68m3 so they know they have filled a container.

And is there a way to flash up a message if a client tries to submit an order less than 68m3 indicating to them that they still have room left in their container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $cart_prods_m3 = array();

        //LOOP ALL THE PRODUCTS IN THE CART
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());
            //GET GET PRODUCT M3 
            $prod_m3 = $_product->get_length() * 
                       $_product->get_width() * 
                       $_product->get_height();
            //MULTIPLY BY THE CART ITEM QUANTITY
            //DIVIDE BY 1000000 (ONE MILLION) IF ENTERING THE SIZE IN CENTIMETERS
            $prod_m3 = ($prod_m3 * $values['quantity']) / 1000000;
            //PUSH RESULT TO ARRAY
            array_push($cart_prods_m3, $prod_m3);
        } 

    echo "Total of M3 in the cart: " . array_sum($cart_prods_m3);
?>
```

See WC() docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/class-reference/

Comment: Hi there - thx so much for the code - it works albeit for one small issue. When there are 6 items in the basket which is a couple of m3 in volume the display on the screen reads Total of M3 in the cart: 10050600000 - Is there an maths addition issue here or just the formatting of the number? Thx very much

Comment: How are you entering you products sizes? in CM or Metres?

Comment: So if you are entering in CM you need to divide `$prod_m3` by 1000000 (one million lol).. see my updated answer...

Comment: ok all dimensions are are entered in mm! thats how they get given to me for the furniture pierces lol

Comment: Ohh I see... You need to update the Measurements on Wooccommerce -> Settings -> Products to be in `mm`... And in your code, as you're using mm, you need to divide each dimension by 100... See @LoicTheAztec answer..

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function that will get automatically the dimension unit set in Woocommerce and that will do the total cart volume calculation:

```
function get_cart_volume(){
    // Initializing variables
    $volume = $rate = 0;

    // Get the dimetion unit set in Woocommerce
    $dimension_unit = get_option( 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' );

    // Calculate the rate to be applied for volume in m3
    if ( $dimension_unit == 'mm' ) {
        $rate = pow(10, 9);
    } elseif ( $dimension_unit == 'cm' ) {
        $rate = pow(10, 6);
    } elseif ( $dimension_unit == 'm' ) {
        $rate = 1;
    }

    if( $rate == 0 ) return false; // Exit

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) { 
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object and cart quantity
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $qty     = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Get product dimensions  
        $length = $product->get_length();
        $width  = $product->get_width();
        $height = $product->get_height();

        // Calculations a item level
        $volume += $length * $width * $height * $qty;
    } 
    return $volume / $rate;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

**Example usage output:**

```
echo __('Cart volume') . ': ' . get_cart_volume() . ' m3';
```