# Display a notice if shipping volume exceed a defined value in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, volume

I have some php code in a  widget in the sidebar that displays the total m3 volume of their order. As the customer adds items the m3 value increaes.

I want to alert the client when the volume of the order reaches 68m3 which is equvalent to a 40 foot container. Is there a way to take the value from my snippet and display a notification box?

The snippet displaying the volume of the order is using code in this answer [Displaying total sum of shipping Volume of Woocommerce order on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229642/displaying-total-sum-of-shipping-volume-of-woocommerce-order-on-page/49229898?noredirect=1#comment85586263_49229898)

Thx in advance is anyone knows how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered in your [**linked question thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335172/3730754) with a custom function that calculate the cart volume based on the measurement unit set in Woocommerce.

I use that [**`get_cart_volume()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335172/3730754) function in the code below to display a custom notice this way:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'display_volume_alert' );
function display_volume_alert(){
    if( get_cart_volume() >= 68 )
        wc_add_notice( __("Your order total volume has reached more than <strong>68 m3</strong>", "woocommerce"), 'notice' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

[image]