# Setting minimum volume and weight on total order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

First: Please excuse my 0 knowledge in coding. I am trying to learn.
Problem: Some freight-plugins needs a minimum weight and/or volume or they wont send the information to the courier and you need to do it manually.

I am thinking that I need to retrieve the length, height and width and check if they all meet the requirements. If they don't, then I want to add the minimum requirements.

I've searched for how I can fetch the information and found this that LoicTheAztec wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49335172

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) { 
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object and cart quantity
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $qty     = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Get product dimensions  
        $length = $product->get_length();
        $width  = $product->get_width();
        $height = $product->get_height();
```

So this way I extract the info I guess?

So to continue I need to set conditions (in meters)

```
if ($length < 0.15) {
$length = 0.15
}
if ($width < 0.11) {
$width = 0.11
}
if ($height < 0.035) {
$height = 0.035
}
```

Am I on the right track? How do I continue from here?
Edit: Ok seems that's not enough, Somehow I need to send the values also to the checkout. I am completely stuck. Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated.